# DateTime Value from deserialized JSON treated as both string and datetime by compiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm having a frustrating issue.

I'm deserializing a JSON file in an ASP.NET MVC application.  I need to view a date, but I want to format it to make it a bit nicer for the viewer.

In the model, it is a DateTime:

```
namespace Company.Name.PRNImportExportUI.Models
{
    public class NPPRFile
    {
        public string SubmitterID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
```

And in the cshtml for the view

```
@using System.IO;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using Aetna.Medicaid.PRNImportExportUI.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NPPRResponse";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    string nppr = File.ReadAllText(@"\\path\to\testnppr.json");
    NPPRFile NpprResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NPPRFile>(nppr);
}

<section>
    <h2>NPPRResponse</h2>
    <p>Submitter ID: @NpprResponse.SubmitterID</p>
    <p>Transaction Date: @DateTime.Parse(NpprResponse.TransactionDate)</p>
</section>
```

Here's the problem, if I try to parse `NpprResponse.TransactionDate` it says it's not a string, but a `DateTime`.  I get a compiler error and it won't build.  But if I call `NpprResponse.TranscationDate.getType()` I get `System.lang.string`.  And if I call `NpprResponse.TransactionDate.ToString("MM DD YYYY")` it fails to compile because it can't do DateTime formatting on a string.

It's in this weird Schrodinger's Cat with types position here or something.  Why isn't it just treating this property as either a string or a DateTime?  (Preferably a DateTime since that's how it's defined in its model)

Comment: I'm afraid I doubt what you're saying about `NpprResponse.TranscationDate.getType()` returning `System.lang.string` (aside from anything else, it would be `System.String`). What *precise* error do you get when calling `NpprResponse.TransactionDate.ToString("MM DD YYYY")`? Please provide a [mcve], ideally as a console app - I'd be surprised if this were really ASP.NET-specific. (Just try writing the same code elsewhere in your app, for a start.)

Comment: The error: CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider

I also know Java so I think that's how "lang" snuck into `System.String`  But yeah, it says `System.String`

Comment: And if you call `NpprResponse.TransactionDate.FooBar()`, what exact error message does that show? Again, if you could reproduce in a context outside ASP.NET, it would be easier for us to reproduce it in turn.

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a DateTime? `((DateTime)NpprResponse.TransactionDate).ToString("MM DD YYYY")` or perhaps converting it to a string and then parsing `DateTime.Parse(NpprResponse.TransactionDate.ToString()).ToString("MM DD YYYY")`

Comment: JsonConvert will always set it to a date time field... which makes @DateTime.Parse(NpprResponse.TransactionDate) redundant. You should be able to do a NpprResponse.TransactionDate.ToString("MM DD YYYY")